# Passing in postgres sequence as a query statement parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have a sequence set up in postgres EX: seq_id_gen. When I pass in this sequence to my static query the string is passed in and it doesn't get evaluated. Is there a way to strip the quotes? Does anyone know of a way to do this without having to dynamically build this query?

My sql query is

```
INSERT into table (SELECT $1, $2, $3,$4)
```

In my function I am calling this query by

```
query(myquery, ['currval(\'seq_id_gen\')' , param1, param2, param3]);
```

What happens is this statement becomes

```
INSERT into table (SELECT 'currval(\'seq_id_gen\')' , param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: What is the driver? What is the function language?

Comment: javascript, node backend using pg

Comment: Unrelated, but: why this strange insert format? Why don't you use the "standard" way using `insert into table values (...)`

Comment: i believe for postgres the way to use a sequence you would have to use a SELECT statement, normally yes it would be values

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate SQL code in one of your parameters, you will have to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
EXECUTE 'INSERT into table VALUES ('
        || param1 || ', '
        || param2 || ', '
        || param3 || ', '
        || param4 ')';
```

Make dead sure that no user-generated input can be used with a construct like this, as it would make you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).